# How does light so travel so fast?.

Tags: gravity, black-hole, light

I've read that photon's have zero mass, hence no force is needed to accelerate them. But then the second question. How can gravity affect something which has 0 mass?. Yes, gravity(black hole) can bend space and time but how can 0 mass particle be affected by this?. What am i missing.?

Comment: photons don't accelerate, they always travel at the speed of light

Comment: There are many ways to explain this phenomenon, but the one I prefer is this one: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/11911/1378